# How to get appActivity in iOS similar to android in Appium ex. driver.getActivity()?

Tags: automated-tests, appium, ui-automation, appium-android, appium-ios

I want to fetch the current view controller in iOS for validation of current page. In android we have driver.getActivity() method which return the current screen package activity.

I have tried with driver.context() but it is returning the type of app like native or hybrid

Answer (score 0):

IOS doesn't have the concept of activities, its not possible to do so , you can read more info in below git link for same issue

[How to identify current iOS screen (activity)?](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/87#issuecomment-52089492)